# Conditional Statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display a banner image depending on the page the user is on:

```
<?php if ( is_product_category('cocktail-catering-packages') ) { ?>
    <div id="page_caption" class="hasbg parallax " data-image="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/banner08.jpg" data-width="2142" data-height="454">
<?php } ?>
<?php if ( is_product_category('sweet-bites') ) { ?>
    <div id="page_caption" class="hasbg parallax " data-image="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/banner10.jpg" data-width="2142" data-height="454">
<?php } ?>
<?php else { ?>
    <div id="page_caption" class="hasbg parallax " data-image="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/banner04.jpg" data-width="2142" data-height="454">
<?php } ?>
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /home/.../public_html/.../wp-content/themes/.../woocommerce.php on line 513
```

As I am unfamiliar with PHP, could someone please assist me in how I may create this conditional statement.

Comment: Which line is 513? Is it the one containing `<?php else { ?>` ?

Comment: The last three lines provided in the code

Comment: You might want to consider using [Alternative syntax for control sturctures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) in php especially when it comes to building html.  It's a lot easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just writing more legible code would help you diagnose the problem:

```
function showBanner($filename)
{
  $url = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/'.$filename;
  echo '<div id="page_caption" class="hasbg parallax" data-image="'.$url.
       '" data-width="2142" data-height="454">';
}  

if (is_product_category('cocktail-catering-packages')) 
{
  showBanner('banner08.jpg');
}  
else if (is_product_category('sweet-bites'))
{
  showBanner('banner10.jpg');
}
else 
{ 
  showBanner('banner04.jpg');
}
```

Comment: WRONG! There is no `else if` in OP's code!

Comment: Ah, and you spotted that very quickly! :-) I think it's probably an ommision in the question's code.

Comment: If you're wondering i spotted it in 30sec as i read your code!

Comment: Why is this answer getting upvoted and accepted even if it's not even doing what OP's code does?!

Comment: Good question, since you found the real reason of the error message. I guess the suggestion I made is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Just get the `}` before the `else`)

```
<?php if ( is_product_category('cocktail-catering-packages') ) { ?>
    <div id="page_caption" class="hasbg parallax " data-image="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/banner08.jpg" data-width="2142" data-height="454">

<?php } ?>
<?php if ( is_product_category('sweet-bites') ) { ?>
    <div id="page_caption" class="hasbg parallax " data-image="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/banner10.jpg" data-width="2142" data-height="454">

<?php } else { ?>
    //^Here i have the '}' before the else statement and NOT in separate php tags
    <div id="page_caption" class="hasbg parallax " data-image="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/banner04.jpg" data-width="2142" data-height="454">

<?php } ?>
```